# SlidingMenu and header

Tags: android

I begin to use a slidingMenu. In my application I have a header with button. when I move it sliding, than my header move too. But I want, than my header do not move, and sliding menu move under header. My header is not actionBar, usual layout.

```
// configure the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);

    // ///////////
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    // //////////

    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

How I can do what I want?

Comment: Dear Ertt , did you do enough research before asking questions? if not please do it. I got your question though. Stackoverflow community helps you , but make sure your questions meet the community standards. I don't mean that this question is poor. I could find from your profile that you asked around 7 questions and has none as accepted. All these matters. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a button to action toggle from sliding.

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonToggle).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
                }
            });
```